# How can I exclude certain paths from being crawled/indexed?

Tags: google-chrome, search, web-crawler, robots.txt

I have the following url structure on my website:

user accounts:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/username
```

user my contain items that are under:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/username/item/itemId
```

What do I have to set in my robots.txt that the user accounts will not be indexed and all the items will be indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I don't think that's going to be possible with robots.txt. Google's wildcard support probably won't support that if `username`, `item`, and `item-id` can be any arbitrary strings. You'd have to specify each `username`, at minimum.

Check out Google's [Robots.txt Specifications](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) page. There might be some other method of doing what you want.